# Java vs Flash for webcam access

Tags: java, flash, video-streaming, webcam

I will make a video chat website, but coming from PHP and Python for the web i have no experience with video steaming.

What do you recommend? Java or Flash? What's more flexible ?

I am thinking of  even making a C++ server application for stream controlling with a PHP fronted. Since is going to be a high traffic website and performance is a must.

Can you point to some direction?
Any documentation? Framework?

Comment: which one did you choose? I am developing something of similar type, I am looking at various options such as Flash, WebRTC etc but still going through research phase.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to warn you: this is no small project. There's a reason why most prepackaged video chat websites and services cost hundreds of dollars a month.

First off, you need to pick your client side runtime. This is a major decision, since it will impact your available client base, and the cost of entry for your site. Flash is hands down the most pervasive, but Java is fairly prevalent in the techie culture. Silverlight less so, but you should check the latest [statistics](http://www.statowl.com/custom_ria_market_penetration.php). Note that you should pick a particular version you're going to develop for, since the APIs may change, and market penetration is different.

Once you've developed the client-side code, you'll need to pick the server environment. If you use Silverlight, obviously you need to use C#.NET to develop the server side code (for the video streaming). Both Java and Flash as clients use Java as the server-end.

If you choose to go with Flash, be aware that you can either go with the official [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), or you can go with the open-source [Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) server.

Comment: I will go with java for the client, thanks for the Red5 Server tip.

Comment: Btw can i make a server application in C++ ? i am worried about teh perfomance and still make the java bindings ?

Comment: I'd suggest going with a server technology that can scale easily, rather than C++. You really don't need to worry that much about the performance. Just don't write your code to be "efficient" and you'll do fine. It's the attempts to be "efficient" that causes most performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by SEK, you should proceed with caution since providing a reliable streaming service might not be as easy as it sounds.

I would recommend reading about streaming (what it is/means, technologies, etc) and then moving on with the implementation.

**Serving streams to clients**

Solutions like the Flash Media Server, might give you less headaches. Red5, as previously mentioned is a 'nice' open source solution, although i am not sure about the capacity and stability.

You might want to check:

http://www.wowzamedia.com/ (Flash Media Server) - interesting

NOTE: Wowza Media Server 2 for Amazon EC2 is also available

http://mammothserver.org/ (Another Open source Flash Media Server)

http://fmsguru.com/ (Flash Media related tutorials)

Google is always your friend on this big topic..good luck.